# lacks an accompanying binding - What does it mean? How it works?

Tags: haskell, haskell-platform

I am practising from LYAH.

phoneBook.hs file contains following code:

```
phoneBook :: [(String, String)]
```

While trying to compile the above-mentioned code I am getting following error:

```
*Main> :load "/home/optimight/phoneBook.hs"
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( /home/optimight/phoneBook.hs, interpreted )

/home/optimight/phoneBook.hs:1:1:
    The type signature for `phoneBook' lacks an accompanying binding
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Question added after brano's answer and subsequent comment to this answer:  How do we provide implementation for above-mentioned  type signature?

If I add this :

```
type phoneBook = [(String, String)]
```

I am getting following error:

```
Prelude> :load "/home/optimight/phoneBook.hs"
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( /home/optimight/phoneBook.hs, interpreted )

/home/optimight/phoneBook.hs:2:6:
    Malformed head of type or class declaration: phoneBook
Failed, modules loaded: none
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to provide an implementation for phoneBook.

`phoneBook :: [(String, String)]`   is just the signature.

Comment: Why it is compulsory to provide an implementation? If I am developing a haskell application and if phoneBook is part of it, I will never bundle any data in it. It will be a blank phoneBook.

Comment: How do we provide implementation for this?

Comment: @Optimight e.g. `phoneBook = []`. Whatever value you choose to put here will be the value during the entire program execution. Instead of defining a top level value, `phoneBook` should probably be a function parameter or (part of) the state in a `State` or a `StateT` function.

Comment: with your implementation you are sayin that phoneBook is a function returning a list of string pair. You need to specify the implementation in order to use it. Maybe this is not what you want to do. Do you want to make a type definition? In that case you should type "type phoneBook = [(String,String)]

Comment: @dave4420: I could not understand your comment due to my very limited knowledge of haskell. Can you please give elaborate explanation along with the code, you are suggesting.

Comment: brano: With type phoneBook = [(String, String)] , I am getting this error: Prelude> :load "/home/optimight/phoneBook.hs"
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( /home/optimight/phoneBook.hs, interpreted )

/home/optimight/phoneBook.hs:2:6:
    Malformed head of type or class declaration: phoneBook
Failed, modules loaded: none.

Comment: could you please provide the whole code? And also explain what you are trying to acchieve?

Comment: when you define a type in haskell it needs to start with a capital letter. so type PhoneBook = [(String,String)]. This essentially means that each time you refer PhoneBook you will actually refer to a list of string pairs.

Comment: @brano With the given type signature `phoneBook` is not a function that returns a list of pairs, it is a list of pairs. If it was a function, its type would include a `->`.

Comment: @sepp2k yes i know ;) if you read the comments above i just gave him the type definition if that was the case he wanted. Did I state anywhere that it was a function :S

Comment: @brano Yes, you said: "with your implementation you are sayin that phoneBook is a function returning a list of string pair."

Comment: @sepp2k. If you look at his first post he writes phoneBook::[(String,String)] this is a function returning a list of string pairs. This function does not take any arguments but it is still a function that needs an implementation. If you want the phoneBook to be a list of pairs you need to write type PhoneBook = [(String,String)] then PhoneBook IS a list of string pairs.

Comment: @brano That's utterly and entirely false. There is no such thing as a function of no arguments in Haskell. Any value whose type does not contain a `->`, is not a function. If you write `type PhoneBook = [(String, String)]` then PhoneBook is the type of lists of pairs, but it's not itself a list or any other kind of value - it's a type.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14509/discussion-between-brano-and-sepp2k)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to declare a type, it must have initial upper case i.e. `type PhoneBook = [(String, String)]`.

If you want to declare a function then you need to provide either just its definition (the binding) or both its definition and its type signature. The minimal effort to compile your code is:

```
phoneBook :: [(String, String)]
phoneBook = undefined
```

Then you can replace `undefined` with any value of type `[(String, String)]` e.g. `[("Person","Number")]`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and this was what I was doing initially

```
lst3 :: [a] -> (a , a , a)
lst  xs = if (length xs /= 3)
          then error "Undefined"      
          else (xs !! 0,xs !! 1,xs !! 2)
```

As you can see the Function signature doesn't correspond to when I'm passing it the parameters and this is to be written as:

```
lst3 :: [a] -> (a , a , a)
lst3  xs = if (length xs /= 3)
          then error "Undefined"
          else (xs !! 0,xs !! 1,xs !! 2)
```